# Limitations of HockeyApp for iOS Enterprise App distribution

Tags: ios, ipa, hockeyapp, in-house-distribution, ios-enterprise

I was looking for platforms which can host over-the-air distribution of iOS enterprise App. I came to know about HockeyApp but I dont know the limitations. Can anyone clarify following points:

1. Is there any trial period for free account?
2. Is there any expiry date for distribution URL?
3. How many members, developers, testers and owners can be added to a free account?
4. How many Apps can be added to free account?
5. How many new invites can be sent to members?

Comment: Did you visit https://hockeyapp.net/ I guess here (pricing/FAQ) you can find all answers that you're looking. here are the answer according to my current understanding.
 1. `NO` 2. `expiration date of your provisioning profile` 3. `No Limit` 4. `10` 5.`No limit`

Comment: I went through your suggested link. I was helpful. thnks.

Comment: Point #2 - I'm using enterprise build for ios, so i think it wont expire.. Right??

Comment: Yes I didn't face but it's depends on expiration date of your developer profile.

Answer (score 1):

1. There was previously but starting January 1st, 2018, HockeyApp will be completely free: https://www.hockeyapp.net/blog/2017/12/19/hockeyApp-is-now-free-for-all-developers.html
2. There is no expiration date on the URLs
3. See 1.; from January 1st, it will all be unlimited.
4. See 1.; from January 1st, there will be no limit.
5. There is no limit.